# How can I install docker-ce alongside kubernetes on debian when using containerd?

Tags: debian, docker, kubernetes

debian/11, kubernetes/1.26.1

I have a Debian 11 host running as the control plane node for a Kubernetes deployment. This deployment uses containerd as the container engine. I'd like to install docker-ce on that host. When I try to do so, apt wants to remove containerd:

```bash
[chris@alpha ~]$ sudo apt install docker-ce
[sudo] password for chris:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libc-devtools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  containerd.io
Suggested packages:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount | cgroup-lite
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  containerd runc
```

It also mentions installing containerd.io, but I can't find any information as to whether this is package is a 1:1 replacement for containerd... any thoughts?

Comment: compared with the debian repos, the docker.com repo includes later versions runc (version 1.1.4 vs 1.0.0rc93) and containerd (version 1.6.15 vs 1.4.13) - to see what versions you are actually running, simply run `runc -v` and `containerd -v` then you can check if there's any possible (breaking) issues between the version you are running vs the version that `containerd.io` will install

Comment: That's my confusion -- I'm running containerd v1.6.15 presently because I pulled it from bullseye/unstable: 
```[chris@alpha ~]$ containerd -v  
containerd containerd.io 1.6.15 5b842e528e99d4d4c1686467debf2bd4b88ecd86```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containerd.io is an exact replacement for the package containerd. (You just need to look at the [repository packages](https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/bullseye/nightly/binary-amd64/Packages) file list.)

But it is specifically coming from the Docker Repository, because it there can be updated in combination with the Docker Container Engine and other components. Debian has a more conservative way of updating packages and backports fixes and vulnerabilities most of the time without upgrading the package to an upstream version.

To give you a better overview, [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-is-containerd-and-how-does-it-relate-to-docker-and-kubernetes/) is a short summary of Docker, Kubernetes and Containerd:

- Docker – A developer-oriented software with a high level interface that lets you easily build and run containers from your terminal. It now uses containerd as its container runtime.
- Containerd – An abstraction of kernel features that provides a relatively high level container interface. Other software projects can use this to run containers and manage container images.
- Kubernetes – A container orchestrator that works with multiple container runtimes, including containerd. Kubernetes is focused on deploying containers in aggregate across one or more physical “nodes.” Historically, Kubernetes was tied to Docker.

Comment: The answer to my question is in the first link.  Thank you for showing me the packages file.